# Java: How to properly manipulate BigDecimal array using functional programming?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, bigdecimal

So, how to get outcome of this code using functional programming:

```
public static final List<BigDecimal> numbers = Arrays.asList(
    new BigDecimal("15"), new BigDecimal("10"), new BigDecimal("17"),
    new BigDecimal("30"), new BigDecimal("18"), new BigDecimal("23"),
    new BigDecimal("5"), new BigDecimal("12") );

BigDecimal totalOfReducedNumbers = BigDecimal.ZERO;
   for(BigDecimal number : numbers) {
       if(number.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(20)) > 0) 
           totalOfReducedNumbers = 
         totalOfReducedNumbers.add(number.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9)));
   }
System.out.println("Total of reduced numbers: " + totalOfReducedNumbers);
```

Which throws out "***Total of reduced numbers: 47.7***"

**How to get the same outcome using functional programming tools** like map(), reduce() etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The for loop implementation is a typical "reduce" pattern (also known as "fold", "Aggregate" pattern in some other languages)

You're looking for `filter` --> `reduce` method:

```
BigDecimal reduce = 
         numbers.stream()
                .filter(n -> n.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(20)) > 0)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, 
                       (a, b) -> a.add(b.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9))));
```

You can further minimise the number of objects contructed by caching `BigDecimal.valueOf(20)` and `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9)` as shown in @Elliot's answer i.e.:

```
BigDecimal TWENTY = BigDecimal.valueOf(20);
BigDecimal POINT9 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9);
BigDecimal reduce = 
             numbers.stream()
                    .filter(n -> n.compareTo(TWENTY) > 0)
                    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, 
                           (a, b) -> a.add(b.multiply(POINT9)));
```

Answer (score 10):

By performing the same operations, first filter values (you only want values greater than 20). Then multiply those values by `0.9` and finally reduce the terms by performing addition. Like,

```
BigDecimal TWENTY = BigDecimal.valueOf(20);
BigDecimal POINT9 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9);
System.out.println("Total of reduced numbers: " + numbers.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.compareTo(TWENTY) > 0)
        .map(x -> x.multiply(POINT9)).reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b)).get());
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
Total of reduced numbers: 47.7
```

And, as suggested in the comments, we can further improve that with a method reference and using `orElse` would be safer than a raw `get()`. Like,

```
System.out.println("Total of reduced numbers: " + numbers.stream() 
        .filter(x -> x.compareTo(TWENTY) > 0) 
        .map(x -> x.multiply(POINT9)) 
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add) 
        .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO));
```

Comment: you could change `(a, b) -> a.add(b)` to a method reference `reduce(BigDecimal::add)`, if it makes things more readable... I'd also add `.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)` instead of calling `get()`

Comment: @Aomine A method reference has another advantage over a lambda:  the lambda compiles as an additional anonymous class, while the method reference does not.